# VS 2013 Could not find SDK SQLite.WP81

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sqlite, sdk, windows-phone

I have installed everything, still get error:

Error   3   Could not find SDK "SQLite.WP81, Version=3.8.11.1". MyShop.WinPhoneRT

Answer (score -1):

Hi follow the following steps :

```
 1. First download Sqlite for Windows phone 8.1 from NUGET

 2. Now go throug the error Display path up to SQLite.WP81 folder

 3. go into SQLite.WP81 folder 

 4. Replace Letest version with 3.8.11.1 

 5. Restart your Visual Studio.
```